# Embed HTML resources from internal network within a public https page

Tags: ssl-certificate, https, internal-dns

We have a website for internal use only which however is hosted publicly on a regular internet domain, and it’s secured with https protocol.

However, the page contains http(s) links to resources (images and videos) from the internal network (LAN).

If internal links use http protocol, the browser bloks them because of mixed content rules.

On the other hand, if they are https links, the browser still blocks them since the hostname written in the certificate does not match the hostname requested by the browser. This is due to the fact that the browser reaches the internal http server through its internal IP address, or its internal hostname. As far as I know, we can’t obtain valid SSL certificates for internal names or networks, and on the other hand, the public certificate we own does not match the internal server’s hostname.

Are these troubles a sign of poor infrastructure design?

Is there anything I can do to get everything working?

Importing a self signed certificate or a custom CA is not an option, since it involves collaboration from users, which I can't count on.

Using the Split-horizon DNS facility is undesirable, since it would introduce an additional single point of failure. I mean, if the Split-horizon DNS went down, it would cut off the whole Internet connectivity to all apps (not just the web browser), and to all the devices in the LAN. I know that this scenario applies to the router DNS forward service as well, but users tend to accept that Internet connectivity goes down when the router breaks down, while they don’t accept an Internet black out when it’s caused by an internal service, such as internal DNS indeed is, which was supposed to help running the internal website **only**.

Making the public https server acting as a proxy for (or forwarding in any way) the internal resources is also undesirable, since it would cause bandwidth overhead, which the original network architect wanted to avoid from the beginning by linking resources from the internal network.

Comment: You seem to have ruled out all the options. You need a reverse proxy. Is the extra bandwidth really a concern?